# Ruby on Rails - why i am facing possible unmatched constraints[:exercise_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5.1

```
def edit    
  @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:exercise_id])      
  @play = @exercise.plays.find(params[:id])    
end

def update    
  @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:exercise_id])
  @play = @exercise.plays.find(params[:id])    
  if @exercise.plays.update_attributes(play_params)       
    redirect_to @exercise_path      
  else    
    render action: :edit    
  end
end
```

partial view that is being rendered to show all created plays has

```
<p><%= play.name %></p>
<p><%= play.sets %></p>
<p><%= play.reps %></p>
<%= link_to "edit", edit_exercise_play_path( @exercise, play) %>
```

that is plays_controller :edit, :update method, Actually i have two classes, one is `ExerciseController` and other one is `PlaysController`, `ExerciseController` `has_many` plays, i am rendering two partials one to create play and other one to show that play on same page on the partial which is rendering the play after creation, but now i want to add edit feature with edit_exercise_play_path,

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_exercise_play_path(@play) %>
```

after this i am facing unmatched constraint error.Thanks

```
resources :exercises do
resources :plays
end
```

Show.html.erb from ExercisesController

```
<h2>Your Workout Details </h2>
<p><%= @exercise.workout  %></p>
<p><%= @exercise.mode %></p>
<p><%= @exercise.date.strftime("on %A at %H:%M Dated as %d %B") %></p>
<p><%= @exercise.length %></p><br />
<h3> Games you Played </h3>
<%= render @exercise.plays %>
<h3>Add new Game </h3>
<%= render 'plays/form' %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_exercise_path %> |  |
<%= link_to "Destroy", exercise_path(@exercise), :confirm => "Are you 
sure?", :method => :delete %> | |
<%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
```

> " Logs "
>   Started GET "/exercises/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-25 18:12:21 +0500
>   Processing by ExercisesController#show as HTML
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
>     Exercise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>     Rendering exercises/show.html.erb
>     Play Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "plays".* FROM "plays" WHERE "plays"."exercise_id" = ?  [["exercise_id", 5]]
>     Rendered collection of plays/_play.html.erb [6 times] (14.0ms)
>     Rendered exercises/show.html.erb (39.7ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 136ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Can you share your routes here.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Routes added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your routes, the path helper `edit_exercise_play_path` also require value for `:exercise_id` key. But you haven't passing any. Changing the `link_to` to below should fix your problem

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_exercise_play_path(@exercise, @play) %>
```

**Update:**

As per our discussion over the chat, the `link_to` edit should look like below

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_exercise_play_path(@exercise, play) %>
```

as you are rendering a partial with `<%= render @exercise.plays %>` which creates a `play` variable.

> undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

For this, you should change `<%= render 'form' %>` to `<%= render 'form' , exercise: @exercise, play: @play %>` and in the `_form.html.erb` change the first line of the form to `<%= simple_form_for ([exercise, play]) do |f| %>`

> undefined method `update_attributes' for
>   Play::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000000f69c710

The reason for this error is in your update method you have have `@exercise.plays.update_attributes(play_params)`. This means you are calling `update_attributes` on collection. You should change

```
if @exercise.plays.update_attributes(play_params)
```

to

```
if @play.update_attributes(play_params)
```

Comment: i applied these changes and it showed me that error, No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"plays", :exercise_id=>"5", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: i changed it to,<%= link_to "Edit", edit_exercise_play_path(@exercise, play) %> it worked but created the new play.

Comment: @WaseyRaza Can you update question with the server log that appears when click on edit link?

Comment: @WaseyRaza In which view page you have that link? can you also update the question with that view page code?

Comment: Sure, see the question

Comment: @WaseyRaza Ok, now update the question with `show` method of `exercises_controller.rb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180738/discussion-between-pavan-and-wasey-raza).

Comment: @WaseyRaza I've updated my answer as per our discussion.